# YUICompressor: wrong minification of jquery 1.4.2

Tags: jquery, yui-compressor

When I am trying to compress jQuery with YUICompressor on UNIX machine, it adds some strange words which causes crash on jquery init:

```
(function(window,undefined){var jQuery=function(selector,context){return new jQuery.fn.init(selector,context)}get ,_jQuery=window.jQuery
```

Note 'get ' before ,_jQuery=window.jQuery. There is no 'get ' in source code of course.

When compressing on windows machine all things are ok.

Any clues?

Comment: The same tool in different environments produces different results - it's probably a bug.

Comment: What version of YUI Compressor?  2.4.2 seems to the be latest release.  Also, are you passing any command line options run you run it?  Do you have the same version of Java on your unix machine?

Answer (score 0):

On [day 1](http://jquery14.com/day-01/jquery-14) of the "14 days of jQuery," it is mentioned you can download jQuery already minified:

> As usual, we provide two copies of
>   jQuery, one minified (we now use the
>   Google Closure Compiler as the default
>   minifier) and one uncompressed (for
>   debugging or reading).

Also, check out [jQuery compiled with Google Closure Compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691861/jquery-compiled-with-google-closure-compiler).

Comment: yeah, nice! but I have asked about compression problem of YUICompressor. When developing production code, you need uncompressed JS for dev environment and compressed JS for prod environment. And that is pretty nasty to make special exceptions for already compressed files.

Comment: The standard is to conditionally include either the full version or the minified version based on the environment. So, both versions are in your source, but depending on your environment one or the other is linked to. Depending on your technology, framework, or build process, you can alternately rename/overwrite the non-minified version with the pre-minified version at post-build/deploy time.